# Clean Install Using Windows 7 RTM Upgrade

Tags: windows-7

I am thinking about getting a pre-order for Windows 7 upgrade, but I don't want to buy it if I can't do clean installs with it. How does the upgrade process work exactly when comming from Windows Xp or Vista? I've poked around on Google, but I have only been able to find documentation regarding the Windows 7 RC to RTM migration.

Would I have to install Windows Xp or Vista first every time I wish to format and reinstall Windows 7 on my computer? Or would I just have to, for example, punch in my old Xp/Vista product key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/07/11/windows-7-rc-users-will-be-able-to-install-windows-7-upgrade-dis/), you will need to have an activated copy of XP, Vista, or 7 RC first:

> Now here's the bigger catch: While you
>   won't need to downgrade from Windows 7
>   RC to Vista or XP in order to install
>   Windows 7 final the first, time, you
>   will need to install one of those
>   operating systems and activate it
>   first if you want to do a clean
>   install in the future. Because the
>   Windows 7 upgrade disc will only work
>   with an activated version of Windows.
>   That means you'll need an activated
>   version of Windows XP, Vista, or
>   Windows 7 RC to start with or the disc
>   will be useless.

Comment: Original source is here: http://blogs.chron.com/techblog/archives/2009/07/a_major_windows_7_upgrade_question_gets_an_an.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Although not the answer from Microsoft that I wanted to hear :(

Comment: You definitely aren't the only one disappointed by this.

Comment: I wonder if they will leave in a loophole this time like they did with Vista. However, since the term "activated" is being used, I've have to guess there will be no loophole.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it.
Paul Thurrott documented atleast 3 different ways to do it:

http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp

**Method #1: Just perform a clean install**

Many, many readers report that they have been able to simply treat the Windows 7 Upgrade media as if it were Full media, and that it just works.

**Method #2: Registry hack**

- Change in
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Setup/OOBE/
  value of MediaBootInstall from 1 to   0.
- Run as administrator following command `slmgr /rearm`
- Restart
- Start activate utility

**Method #3: The good old "double install" method**

- Install Windows 7 as custom install on clean hard drive
- Install Windows 7 again now as upgrade
- Activate it

See that link above for more details.

Comment: I used Method #2 on my laptop and it worked as advertised.  I bought a new larger & faster hard drive specifically to install Windows 7 on and I didn't want to have to reload the OEM supplied (bloat infested) OS only to install W7 over it.

Answer (score 2):

The upgrade versions will not do a clean install onto a blank hard drive. The install process will have to be started from an already installed and activated copy of windows. You will then be able to choose whether the install does an inplace upgrade (vista only) or installs a clean copy of Windows 7 (in which case the old windows files will be moved to a folder called Windows.Old).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but it looks like it can be done:

- [Performing Clean Install of Windows 7 with Upgrade Disk](http://topsecretsupport.com/index.php?topic=545.0)
- [How to clean install from Windows 7 Upgrade media](http://windows7news.com/2009/10/22/how-to-clean-install-from-windows-7-upgrade-media/)

But whether this won't be blocked by MS at some later stage is a whole another deal.