# Installing Windows 7 upgrade version on a clean disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, upgrade, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean Install Using Windows 7 RTM Upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/1986/clean-install-using-windows-7-rtm-upgrade)

Is it possible to install the much cheaper Windows 7 upgrade version on a clean disk?  What information will I need?

1) Will the Windows 7 installer ask me for my XP license key?
or
2) Will the Windows 7 installer only run if it can detect an existing XP installation?

Furthermore, what will happen if my disk crashes and I need to reinstall in the future?  Will I need my XP license key again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it looks like it can be done:

- [Performing Clean Install of Windows 7 with Upgrade Disk](http://topsecretsupport.com/index.php?topic=545.0)
- [How to clean install from Windows 7 Upgrade media](http://windows7news.com/2009/10/22/how-to-clean-install-from-windows-7-upgrade-media/)

But whether this won't be blocked by MS at some later stage is a whole another deal.