# Doing a clean windows 7 install from an upgrade disk with and upgrade key

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows 7 upgrade version on a clean disk](https://superuser.com/questions/59264/installing-windows-7-upgrade-version-on-a-clean-disk)

I just finished a clean install of windows 7 with an upgrade disk. When I enter the upgrade key, it complains that the key is not meant for clean installs.

What are my options?

I have a valid vista key. Is there any way I can deal with this without reinstalling the os?

Comment: This issue has been resolved before, check out this question: http://superuser.com/questions/59264/installing-windows-7-upgrade-version-on-a-clean-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to validate the install over the phone.  This is what I did after trying a variety of other alleged solutions and it worked so well I regretted not trying it earlier.