# How do install of "Windows 7 Upgrade" on VirtualBox (for use on OS X) w/ minimal disk use?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, upgrade, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean Install Using Windows 7 RTM Upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/1986/clean-install-using-windows-7-rtm-upgrade)

I have a license for Windows 7 upgrade, and want to use it via VirtualBox on OS X.  Because the Upgrade license doesn't work on a fresh install of Windows, the trick that I've always used is to install Windows, not enter the license key, and then after the install finishes, "upgrade" that copy of windows.  Unfortunately, this copies all the files to disk, and replaces all the just-installed windows files over again.  This is not a big deal if I have the temporary hard drive space, but with VirtualBox, my space is limited.

Currently I am at the point where Windows 7 is installed, but no valid license is entered. I now need to "upgrade" windows for my key to work.  This requires 15gb of free space though, and my virtualbox image doesn't have that space (max=20gb, and already is using 12gb).

I need to keep my virtualbox image small because I'm on a SSD.  I'm willing to temporarily increase the virtualbox image to 30gb, but VirtualBox says once a disk image grows, there is no shrinking it.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to install a "upgrade" license without this dual-install hack described above?
2. Any trick to shrink my virtualbox image?

**EDIT**
Question 3: Any other software like Parallels that would handle my task better?

Answer (score 0):

Found this for resizing: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=10348

I'll probably just start over with my windows install, and set max hard drive size to 40gb, and resize if needed.