# How do I clean-install a new SSD with Windows 7 upgrade DVD

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-installation

I'm adding some new fancy pieces to my computer from HP. I now have a legitimate copy of Windows 7 home premium that comes from an upgrade DVD from Windows Vista that was given me with the computer itself.

At this moment I have three recovery DVDs. Windows Vista Home Premium SP1. The burning of the DVD from the computer didn't work so they sent me those three DVDs from HP.

I then have an HP upgrade assistant DVD and a Windows 7 Home Premium upgrade media that seems to require a compatible Windows Vista on the drive.

So that's the question: How should I do it the right way?

As I understood I should first install Windows Vista and then run a clean install from the upgrade media. Will the recovery disc work with a different PC than the original (I am changing HDD, video card, amount of RAM, PSU, but I still have the same motherboard and CPU)?

I want to keep the old HDD for mass data storage. I want to format it to clean the system a little. When do I add the disk (from the start?) to format it?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/62881/138343 for clean installing using Win7 upgrade media (i.e. without needing to install Vista first). As for your old HDD, for best results I advise you to connect it after Win7 is up and running on your SSD. You can easily format and partition it from within the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert Windows 7 Disk and boot from it.

Delete any partitions on the SSD and do a clean install.

When prompted for Licence Key, leave it blank and click next.

When prompted for OS Version, choose the version you will ultimately be using.

Install Windows.

After windows is installed, reboot from the disk, and choose UPGRADE.  Enter your license Key,  and away you go.

Comment: do i need a standard windows 7 disk or can i use the upgrade disk?

Comment: If I recall correctly, all the retail discs are the same.  Any disc should do the trick.